# F# can't understand the delimitation my multiple argument values have. Why?

Tags: .net, f#

I'm actually facing a potentially strange problem with the F# compiler. The following code gives me an error and I can't understand why:

```
    yield Animal(
        AnimalType(animal.AnimalType.Value),
error-->if Option.isSome animal.AnimalSubType then Some(AnimalSubType(animal.AnimalSubType.Value)) else None,
        AnimalSpecificSubType(animal.AnimalSpecificSubType.Value)
        )
```

The compiler complains that Animal should take 3 arguments but is in fact only taking 2. I guess it is failing to realize that the if argument ends at the end of the line (in the comma). I can get the code running by adding ()'s around the offending line:

```
    yield Animal(
        AnimalType(animal.AnimalType.Value),
--> OK  (if Option.isSome animal.AnimalSubType then Some(AnimalSubType(animal.AnimalSubType.Value)) else None),
        AnimalSpecificSubType(animal.AnimalSpecificSubType.Value)
        )
```

but I'd like to understand the issue. Why does this fix the issue and, for instance, this does not?

```
    yield Animal(
        AnimalType(amimal.AnimalType.Value),
error-->if (Option.isSome animal.AnimalSubType) then (Some(AnimalSubType(animal.AnimalSubType.Value))) else (None),
        AnimalSpecificSubType(animal.AnimalSpecificSubType.Value)
        )
```

I've not looked up over F#'s grammar, but I'd guess every time F# sees an `if` clause it will expect an `else` clause, potentially followed by an `else` clause. I'd guess that as long as I was careful with the `else` clause everything would be fine.

What's the matter here?

Comment: lol, spot on. but it was a copy-paste issue. i've fixed it in the OP.

Comment: That seems like a good guess.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted that because in that case it wouldn't type check. But maybe it doesn't get that far because of the mismatching args error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler interprets the comma at the end of the error line as part of a tuple returned by the `else` branch, i.e.

```
yield Animal(
    a,
    if c then Some(b) else None,
    d 
    )
```

is parsed as:

```
yield Animal(
    a,
    if c then Some(b) else ((None, ...? )
    d 
    )
```

That's why your first fix works and not the second, as adding brackets in the second fix just wraps the first element of the phantom tuple, not the tuple itself, i.e.:

```
yield Animal(
    a,
    if c then Some(b) else (None),
    d 
    )
```

is parsed as:

```
yield Animal(
    a,
    if c then Some(b) else ((None), ...? )
    d 
    )
```

Comment: Doesn't it make `d` part of the second argument? I.e. `yield Animal(a,((if c then Some(b) else None),d))`?

Comment: @mydogisbox : Right, hence why the compiler is complaining that there are only two arguments to the `Animal` constructor. +1 on your answer. ;-]

Answer (score 3):

The problem has to do with how tuples are created in F#:

```
> let test (a,b,c) = "Test"
> test(1, if true then Some 1 else None,1);;

  test(1, if true then Some 1 else None,1);;
  -----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'a * 'b * 'c    
but given a
    'a * 'b    
The tuples have differing lengths of 3 and 2
```

This makes it clear that the compiler thinks `test` is taking two parameters, but what does the compiler think these two parameters are?  Since functions of this type are really just functions which take a single parameter as a tuple, we can deconstruct that line of code a bit like so:

```
> 1, if true then Some 1 else None,1;;

  1, if true then Some 1 else None,1;;
  ----------------------------^^^^^^

stdin(19,29): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    int option    
but here has type
    'a * 'b
```

So you can see that the compiler is treating `None,1` as the expression in the `else` of the `if` expression which is why the compiler is expecting an `int option`.  To prevent this, you need to indicate to the compiler where the start and end of the `if` expression are.  The easiest way of achieving this is by simply putting parenthesis around it like this:

```
> 1,(if true then Some 1 else None),1;;
val it : int * int option * int = (1, Some 1, 1)
```

Now we get the expected tuple.